Meaning of residual resistivity in high-$T_c$ materials
I recently came across this paper titled "Universal Tc depression by irradiation defects in underdoped and overdoped cuprates" studying the effect of disorder on high-$T_c$ materials. The statement is that increasing the disorder only increases the residual resistivity, but not the slope of the linear in temperature curve above $T_c$. I am, however, confused by what is meant by residual resistivity here. Usually, I would say that residual resistivity is $\rho(T=0)$, i.e., the remaining resistance at zero Kelvin. Here, however, we are dealing with a superconductor, meaning that it always has $\rho(T=0)=0$. Is it correct that what they mean by residual resistivity here is the resistivity right above $T_c$?

For a superconductor, the way to access the "true" residual resistivity would be either to apply magnetic field to destroy the superconductivity, or to extrapolate the normal state resistivity to zero temperature. The high critical temperatures (and high critical fields) of the cuprates make both of these options difficult, ambiguous, or impossible.

Is one way to then estimate this (what would be) residual resistivity then to just fit the straight line in temperature and see where it intersects the vertical axes? For instance, there is a sentence in https://arxiv.org/abs/0711.0877 "An estimation of the residual resistivity due to the impurities can be obtained either by extrapolation of the
high T behavior to T = 0..."? Further, why is one interested in this residual resistivity?

Yes that is one common way to estimate it. However, because in the cuprates you are extrapolating from very high temperatures, it is not clear that you can get a trustworthy number from this extrapolation. We are usually interested in residual resistivity because it essentially measures the elastic scattering rate (scattering from disorder).
